# Where does skype store downloads?

Tags: macos, finder, skype

After downloading an attachment in skype, which is saved to my ~/Downloads folder, the attachment won't show up in de Downloads-folder until I click the 'eye' or 'magnifying glass' icons overlaying the download in the skype-message window.

Even when listing the files in the Downloads-folder in terminal, the skype downloads won't show up.

Where are the files downloaded in a skype message stored, until I click one of the two 'Reveal in finder'-icons (resolved in update 1)

**Question**: Is there a setting/possibility, to automatically make the attachements show up in the Downloads-folder without having to click on them aftet the download is completed?

**UPDATE 1**:
The files seem to be located in `/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/com.skype.skype/fsCachedData`

**UPDATE 2**:
I tried writing an automator script, which watches the above folder for new files, automatically renames them to their original names and moves them to ~/Downloads, but I don't know where the original names are stored.
I tried to just change the extension of the files which also failed, as automator only differentiates between file-types, but not different extensions

Comment: If update 1 solves your problem, you should [add it as an answer yourself and accept it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). If not, could you please rewrite the question to emphasize that you're looking for a configuration setting in Skype?

Comment: @Gaurav I would kike to have the attachement show up in the Download folder after the download it completed, without having to click a second time on the file. With big/multiple downloads I would have to scroll to find it to clikc on it, if I've written enough in that conversation to make it leave the visible part of the conversation.

Comment: Can you use a wildcard so you don't need to know the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title of my question

The files are located in `/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/com.skype.skype/fsCachedData`

If someone knows how to get them out of there automatically, I would still like to know

Comment: They are not located for me here as of present date.

Comment: Since serveral Skype updates every download is directly saved to my downloads folder …

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug, but after you download the file, I have to click on the magnifying glass (on mouse over) aka "Reveal in Finder" in order for the file to literally "reveal" itself in my downloads folder. If I do not click the icon, the file is not in downloads.

Comment: The whole question was about not having to click on that magnifying glass …